# Rails 3, ruby 1.8.7 with sqlite3-ruby 1.2.5, ruby 1.9.2 with sqlite3 1.3.8 easy switch Gemfile?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, rvm

My host (site5) is at the moment only offering ruby 1.8.7 but they are changing this soon. So I am preparing my rails apps for ruby 1.9.2 and 2.0. For testing purposes I need to switch between the different ruby versions (am using rvm and gemsets for this).

In ruby 1.8.7 I need to have gem sqlite3-ruby -v 1.2.5 but 
in ruby 1.9.2 I need gem sqlite3 -v 1.3.8 (because of the multi-byte character issue)
I can't use a higher sqlite3-ruby with ruby 1.8.7 because it won't work in production (at the moment)

Is there an easy way to have and switch between two different sets of Gemfiles/Gemfile.lock files? Or to make the Gemfile/Gemfile.lock conditional on the ruby version that is in use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set platform for gems http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/gemfile.5.html

```
gem "sqlite3-ruby", :version => "1.2.5", :platforms => :mri_18
gem "sqlite3-ruby", :version => "1.3.8", :platforms => [:mri_19, :mri_20]
```